# running node.js odometer middleware

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, middleware, node-modules

In my node.js, Express app, I am trying to run the Odometer middleware   from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odometer) . I included it in my code file in the follwing  way:

```
var odometer = require('odometer');
```

When I run the app, in console I get the error message

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\ri\node_modules\odometer\odometer.js:
33:27)
```

Obviously `document` is not available in server side and the main javascript file of odometer uses `document`. So

1) how to run the middleware ?

2) If it is not possible to run this one, is there any other alternative ?

Comment: Odometer is not a middleware. It is meant for the browser and cannot be run (or does not make sense to) on the server. Why would you like to run it on the server instead of the browser?

Comment: @fxenik, I mentioned the link where odometer is kept as a middleware for  node.js. Just to use it node.js server side, I need to run it in server side. If it is not a middleware and not meant to run on server side, how can we install it with the shell command mentioned in the link ?

Comment: Not everything in npm repository is a middleware, they could be any kind of node modules. I think odometer's developer uses npm in order to distribute the code for anyone who would like to contribute to the project and use his grunt setup for example.

Answer (score 0):

Odometer is not a middleware. It works on browser so just include to your html file.

[**How To Use**](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/) *from documentation..*

> Add the js and a theme file to your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/file/odometer-theme-car.css" />
<script src="path/to/your/file/odometer.js"></script>
```

> Any element with class name "odometer" will automatically be made into
>   an Odometer! When you want to update the value, simply update it the
>   same way you normally would.

```
element.innerHTML = 123 // Native, or...
$('.odometer').html(123) // with jQuery
```

Comment: My app, built with nodeJS and Express JS , is trying to run the odometer from serverside.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed "The simplest possible usage is just including the javascript and a theme css file on your page. Add the odometer class to any numbers you'd like to animate on change. You're done."

Comment: see my comment above to fxenik.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed remove downvote as fxenik say "Odometer is not a middleware. It is meant for the browser and cannot be run (or does not make sense to) on the server"

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed The downvote button tooltip says: 'This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not helpful'. I tend to read it as 'This question does not show enough research effort, it is unclear (except to you), or not helpful for anybody else.."

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I aggree with ziyasal. Actually, I believe that if you follow his instructions you would be able to use it in your web app. Don't be too eager to downvote an answer, especially considering that someone spent some of his personal time to answer to your problem.